# How to get UTF-8 displayed properly in Emacs menus?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, menu-bar

I use GNU Emacs 23.4.1 that comes with Debian Wheezy and UTF-8 as system character encoding. When I add bookmark it displays properly in minibuffer and in the buffer, however the bookmark name is mangled in Emacs bookmarks menu ("Jump to bookmark" list to be exact). Any ideas?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but does `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)` help?

Comment: I seem to recall an Emacs bug report about this, but I can't seem to find it. Perhaps someone can confirm whether this has been fixed in more recent Emacs versions. You might also want to specify your window manager / OS. I imagine that you see the same problem in any menu item that contains such a character (e.g. buffer name, in Buffers menu), and that it is unrelated to bookmark names in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved in emacs 24 which comes with Debian Jessie.